# the best way of update entity through a service in idempotent case?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, service, doctrine-orm

suppose I have the entity:

```
class UserEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $email;

// and contruct, getters and setters..

}
```

and in the respective service:

```
class UserService extends BaseService
{
    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        try {
            $user= $this->fetch($id);

            if (! $user instanceof UserEntity) {
                // throw respective exception;
            }

            $user->setName($data['name']);
            $user->setEmail($data['email']);

            $this->entityManager->flush($user);

            return $user;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        } 
    }
}
```

if there is a user such that:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: jhon,
    email: jhon@domain.com
}
```

and the data provided to the service is:

```
$id = 1;
$data = [
     'name' => jhon,
     'email => jhon@domain,com
]
```

then, what is the best way of avoid the innecesary query to database in these cases?
since it is unnecessary to invoke the flush method.
or Doctrine internally is responsible for not doing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [current docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#synchronizing-new-and-managed-entities):

> The flush operation applies to a managed entity with the following semantics:
>
> - The entity itself is synchronized to the database using a SQL UPDATE
>     statement, only if at least one persistent field has changed.
> - No SQL
>     updates are executed if the entity did not change.

When entities become managed (according to one of their ORMInvalidArgumentExceptions):

> An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist

So yeah, Doctrine will make the decision for you.

Comment: thanks, but, is necessary the persist? observe in https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object say that 'You can call $entityManager->persist($product), but it isn't necessary: Doctrine is already "watching" your object for changes.'

Comment: @warlock_apprentice Indeed, it isn't. Updated my answer. I couldn't find docs to support the second quote, the text comes from one of their exceptions.